# How do I return a translated message from a subscription in a catcherror?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I want my catch error to return a new LoginFailure action but with a message that comes from the subscription of the translate service. This implementation is giving me:

> Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type '(err: any, caught: Observable) =>
>   ObservableInput<{}>'.

```
@Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$.ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.Login).pipe(
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap(auth =>
      this.authService.login(auth).pipe(
        map(data => new LoginSuccess({ data: data })),
        catchError(error => {
          this.translateService
          .get('LoginErrorMessage')
          .subscribe((res: string) => {
            of(new LoginFailure(res));
          });
        }
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to `return` the new observable in the catchError method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You get that error because you aren't returning anything from
   `catchError`.
2. You got to return an Observable not a subscription, so use `mergeMap()` (to flatten) the Observable instead of Subscription.
3. Depending you want the receiver of this request to get the message as a success or an error you have got to return an error or a success.

   ```
    @Effect()
     login$ = this.actions$.ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.Login).pipe(
       map(action => action.payload),
       exhaustMap(auth =>
         this.authService.login(auth).pipe(
           map(data => new LoginSuccess({ data: data })),
           catchError(error => {
             return this.translateService
             .get('LoginErrorMessage')
             .pipe(
               mergeMap((res: string) => {
                   return of(new LoginFailure(res)); // to get it in success callback
                   // or return throwError(new LoginFailure(res)) // to get it in error call back
               });
             )
           }
           )
         )
       )
     );
   ```

---

**Update**

In case you don't want to call another observable after you get a Login Error, there is no need of using a flattening operator. A normal `map()` will do.

```
     @Effect()
      login$ = this.actions$.ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.Login).pipe(
        map(action => action.payload),
        exhaustMap(auth =>
          this.authService.login(auth).pipe(
            map(data => new LoginSuccess({ data: data })),
            catchError(error => {
              return this.translateService
              .get('LoginErrorMessage')
              .pipe(
                map((res: string) => {
                    if (you want the response in success callback) {
                        return new LoginFailure(res);
                    }
                    else {
                        // if you want it in error
                        throw "your error"; // say, {error: "I am Error"}
                    }
                });
              )
            }
            )
          )
        )
      );
```

Comment: That actually worked, I was solving the errors also, as you were editing the answer. thank you for your effort man.

Comment: @dazzed: Yeah I had missed a return and `pipe()` :D

Comment: Cool thank you, you were really helpful, Merry Christmas.

Comment: @dazzed: My pleasure, Merry Christmas :)

Comment: `.pipe(mergeMap((res: string) => of(new LoginFailure(res))));` you should replace it just with `.pipe(map(res => new LoginFailure(res)))` .

Comment: @MaksimRomanenko: I understand your point. I used `mergeMap` in case the OP wanted to throw an error(which I believe he wants). `throwError()` will be an Observable and he will need to use a flattening operator in the case.